# What does glGenVertexArraysOES() do and where is the documentation?

Tags: ios, swift, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm starting with the Swift OpenGL ES "Game" project template in XCode 7 and having a very frustrating time. There seems to be lots of information about using OpenGL ES with Objective C, and some information about using regular OpenGL with Swift, but very little about using OpenGL ES with Swift on iOS.

In the template's GameViewController.swift, in the setupGL() function, there's a call to `glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &vertexArray)`. The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/opengles/1614235-glgenvertexarraysoes) is totally unhelpful. Googling finds lots of people *using* glGenVertexArraysOES(), but nothing documenting what it is or how to use it.

What does this function do, and where is it documented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`glGenVertexArraysOES`generates vertex arrays. Vertex arrays can be used to describe how your geometry data (vertices, indices) is stored in a vertex buffer object (which attribute index corresponds to which attribute like position, texture coordinate etc.). There is documentation on [opengl.org](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glGenVertexArrays.xhtml) (the function does the same as the *OES version):

> glGenVertexArrays — generate vertex array object names
>
> glGenVertexArrays returns n vertex array object names in arrays. There
> is no guarantee that the names form a contiguous set of integers;
> however, it is guaranteed that none of the returned names was in use
> immediately before the call to glGenVertexArrays.
>
> Vertex array object names returned by a call to glGenVertexArrays are
> not returned by subsequent calls, unless they are first deleted with
> glDeleteVertexArrays.
>
> The names returned in arrays are marked as used, for the purposes of
> glGenVertexArrays only, but they acquire state and type only when they
> are first bound

Comment: So I call `glGenVertexArraysOES` and pass it an integer _n_ and a pointer to a GLuint, in this case `vertexArray`. Then it generates _n_ Vertex Array Objects and stores them somewhere, and sets `vertexArray` to a single `uint` which somehow represents a set of _n_ names of the generated VAOs. Is that right?

Comment: Also, is there any difference between the *OES version and the regular?

Comment: If you generate only one array, `vertexArray` can be a single `uint`, if you generate more it should be an array. I don't think there is a difference between the OES and normal version at least for the end-user.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @Robert Strictly speaking, `glGenVertexArrays()` only creates the vertex array *names*. The actual vertex array *object* is only created the first time a name is bound.